# Basic Auth in URL, no authorization header in http context

Tags: c#, http-headers

I'm trying to allow users to hit an endpoint with basic auth by using a url like `username:password@myurl.com\endpoint`.

However, when I check the httpcontext for the authorization header while debugging, it's always null. It's possible I'm just misunderstanding how it works, but I was under the impression that having `username:password@` implies basic auth and attaches it to the header?

Answer (score 0):

**It's not good practice to allow users to pass basic authentication parameters in the url**

Please read the following to understand why this is so [rfc2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)